# FileStream error - The process cannot access the file...used by another process

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, blob, filestream

I have created a method to read from my database, the database has a blob field that stores images.
This method is used to read the Image as well as every other field.
When i run my Application it works and the form displays all the details, but if i close the form and reopen it again, i end up with this error.

> IO Exception was unhandled
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyApp\MyApp\bin\Debug\pic0jpg' because it is being used by another process."

I've tried putting the filestream object in a using statement and other solutions but the error still exists.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
public void loadPlane()
{
    //convert picture to jpg and load other details
    MySqlDataAdapter sqladapt;
    DataSet dataSet;
    DatabaseConnector dbcon = new DatabaseConnector();
    dbcon.OpenConnection();
    sqladapt = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    sqladapt.SelectCommand = dbcon.InitSqlCommand("SELECT * FROM plane");
    dataSet = new DataSet("dst");
    sqladapt.Fill(dataSet);
    dbcon.CloseConnection();

    DataTable tableData = dataSet.Tables[0];
    //use from iplane class
    IPlane.countPlane = tableData.Rows.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < IPlane.countPlane; i++)
    {
        IPlane.planeObj[i] = new NormalPlane();
        DataRow drow = tableData.Rows[i];
        string plName = "pic" + Convert.ToString(i);

        FileStream FSNew = new FileStream(plName+"jpg",FileMode.Create);
        byte[] blob = (byte[])drow[5];
        FSNew.Write(blob,0,blob.Length);
        FSNew.Close();
        FSNew = null;
        
        IPlane.planeObj[i].PlaneImage=(Image.FromFile(plName + "jpg"));
        IPlane.planeObj[i].ModelNumber = drow[0].ToString();
        IPlane.planeObj[i].EngineType = drow[1].ToString();
        IPlane.planeObj[i].FlySpeed = Convert.ToInt32( drow[2]);
        IPlane.planeObj[i].SpecialFeature = drow[3].ToString();
        IPlane.planeObj[i].Price = Convert.ToDouble( drow[4]);
        IPlane.planeObj[i].EconSeats = Convert.ToInt32(drow[6]);
        IPlane.planeObj[i].BussSeats = Convert.ToInt32(drow[7]);
        IPlane.planeObj[i].FirstSeats = Convert.ToInt32(drow[8]);
        //drow 5 is the image
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the main problem:

```
IPlane.planeObj[i].PlaneImage=(Image.FromFile(plName + "jpg"));
```

you are opening the image and leaving it opened.

You have 2 way to go:

- create the image with a memory stream from the blob and not as a file
- create the image as file and use the path of the image as your property `IPlane.planeObj[i].PlaneImage` and load the file when you need it. (I don't understad why you save an image as blob on db and then create the file anyway)

If you don't have many image or they are not so big or you don't have memory problems I think the first is better.

by the way your code has a lots of resources not disposed (connection, streams, etc etc)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, there are a lot of errors because this is just a test code for a method to load details from database. I'll correct them as soon as i try your solution.

Comment: @NimazSheik there aren't a lots of error I was too rough. you have only some object not disposed. just put everything that is IDisposable in a using :D

Answer (score 2):

You really should be disposing of your DatabaseConnector after closing it. The best practice for this would be to use a Using Statement:

```
using (DatabaseConnector dbcon = new DatabaseConnector)
{
   // Code that uses connection. 
}
```

Alternatively, just call dbcon.Dispose() after you call .CloseConnection()

This will ensure ALL resources used by DatabaseConnection are released.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i'll make sure to close all the connections.

Answer (score 2):

As @giammin noted, you are opening a file but never close it. The code also creates a lot of resources that should be disposed.

Moreover, you don't need to save the file at all unless you want to use it at a later time. You can create an Image object from a stream using [Image.FromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x(v=vs.110).aspx). You can wrap the buffer in a MemoryStream and pass it to Image.FromStream, e.g:

```
using(var stream=new MemoryStream(drow[5]))
{
    var image=Image.FromStream(stream);
    Plane.planeObj[i].PlaneImage = image;
}
```